# SQLite SUM with hierarchy values

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have payment analysis app with the following simplified structure:

Payment

```
CREATE TABLE payments (
payment_Id TEXT NOT NULL, 
payment_type INTEGER NOT NULL, 
payment_name TEXT NOT NULL, 
payment_category INTEGER NOT NULL,
payment_date TEXT NOT NULL,
payment_cost TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(payment_Id))
```

Category

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
category_Id INTEGER NOT NULL,
idRoot TEXT NOT NULL,
category_Name TEXT NOT NULL,
category_Type INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(category_Id))
```

Foreign key: categories.category_Id = payment_category

Categories are structured in a tree hierarchy:

| IdRoot | category_Id | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| - | 0 | Unknown |
| 0. | 1 | Expenses |
| 0.1. | 2 | House |
| 0.1. | 3 | Transport |
| 0.1. | 4 | Travel |
| 0.1.2. | 5 | Internet |
| 0.1.2. | 6 | Groceries |
| 0.1.2. | 7 | Water |
| 0.1.3. | 8 | Car |
| 0.1.3. | 9 | Public Transport |
| 0.1.3.8. | 10 | Gasoline |
| 0.1.3.8. | 11 | Tolls |
| ... | ... | .... |

Payments can be assigned to any category (except category_Id = 0).

I want to know if it is possible using just SQLite (compatible with Android is appreciated) to get all the children categories of a parent category and the sum of the payment_cost assign to every category in that level and its children.

**Example**: given category Transport(category_Id: 3), sqlite will return Car and Public Transport and their sums but the sum of Car will also include the payment_cost assign to Gasoline and Tolls something like this

```
Input: category_Id: 3
Data: 
| payment_name   |  payment_cost| payment_category   |
| ------------   | ----------   | -----------------  |
| Gas Station    | 50,3         | 10                 |
| Metro          | 2,4          | 9                  |
| Tool NY - Phil | 21           | 11                 |
| Car cleaning   | 11           | 8                  |
```

Result

| category_name | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Car | 82,3 (50,3 + 21 + 11) |
| Public Transport | 2,4 |

Thank you in advance for your time and knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` to get the matching roots:

```
select sum(payment_cost)
from payments p join
     categories c
     on p.payment_category = c.category_id cross join
     categories c3
     on c3.category_id = 3
where p.idroot like c3.idroot || '%'
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I am afraid I didn't explain myself properly. Check the edit. I have use a similar solution to get the payments associated with a category and all their children but as you can see in the edit, I want the result to be grouped only by the direct childs of the given category but with the sum of all their children